# How do I prevent Django's admin interface from silently suppressing errors?

Tags: django, django-admin

Suppose I have a simple Django model:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)

    @property
    def my_property(self):
        raise ValueError('Is anyone there')
```

Then in my admin GUI, I show `my_property` as a read-only field.

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    readonly_fields = ['my_property']
```

To my surprise, if any exception is raised in generating a value in the Django admin GUI, Django suppresses the error and just shows a "-" as the value.

It took me some time to realize this was the case.

Is there a way to force Django to show exceptions when exceptions occur?

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of this implementation for AdminReadOnlyField:

```
field, obj, model_admin = self.field['field'], self.form.instance, self.model_admin
try:
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field, obj, model_admin)
except (AttributeError, ValueError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
    result_repr = self.empty_value_display
```

So it will silently suppress those 3 exceptions.
One solution could be to create a decorator like:

```
from functools import wraps

class ReadonlyFieldError(Exception):
        pass


def catch_field_exception(func):
    """
    Django silenty suppresses AttributeError, ValueError, ObjectDoesNotExist exceptions that occur during processing of
    custom readonly admin fields.
    Add this decorator to re-raise exception so it is not missed
    :param func:
    :return:
    """
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            raise ReadonlyFieldError('Exception occurred while processing Admin field "{}": {}'.format(func.__name__,
                                                                                                       str(e))) from e
    return wrapped_func
```

Then decorate your method with this:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)

@catch_field_exception
@property
def my_property(self):
    raise ValueError('Is anyone there')
```